# Matlab not showing contents of FTP Object

Tags: matlab, ftp

I have been trying to download files from an ftp server and having problems. I am using 'ftp.m' to get the ftp object and then using 'dir.m' to list the available files and folders. However, the dir command is not returning any information after execution.

I want to download files from the following ftp server:
ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov

```
ftpobj = ftp('cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov')
List = dir(ftpobj)
```

It returns an empty matrix.
Please help.

Comment: Does the example script in https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftp.dir.html work for you? Could you please edit your question to show exactly how you are calling `ftp` and `dir`?

Comment: I have added the lines of my code. It is not only for this ftp, I am receiving empty matrix after using dir even for the examples given on the web page of Mathworks you have shared. above.